# How to quote and reference SQL Server table and field names

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good day!

Despite the fact LINQ2SQL and ADO.NET Entity Framework exists there were situations when I need to revert to plain old DataSet (not typed) and friends.

While writing SQL for SqlCommand:

- Is it needed to quote field and table names with []?
- Is it good to prefix table names with [dbo]

I use to use this syntax:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Field1], [Field2] FROM [dbo].[TableName]", connection);
```

May be there is a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use [] when you are querying your data form the database.

you use [] when there is space of alias name like

```
SELECT Field1 as [First Name], Field2 as [Last Name] FROM [dbo].[TableName]
```

because it gives syntax error

dbo is the schema name that with which your table and the user attached

here is more detail answer 
A database schema is a way to logically group objects such as tables, views, stored procedures etc. Think of a schema as a container of objects.

You can assign a user login permissions to a single schema so that the user can only access the objects they are authorized to access.

Schemas can be created and altered in a database, and users can be granted access to a schema. A schema can be owned by any user, and schema ownership is transferable.

You can also read full article on : http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2008/tutorial/sql_server_database_schemas.cfm

Answer (score 2):

> Is it needed to quote field and table
>   names with []?

No, unless you have a table called [foo bar] (with space), or your column/table (and database name even) starts with a number, or has non-alphanumeric characters.

[See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

> Is it good to prefix table names with
>   [dbo]

Absolutely yes. It allows plan re-use, simply, because object references are now qualified

Answer (score 0):

You only need to quote fields if they represent reserved keywords or contains illegal characters such as in "Field #1". Both the " " (space) and "#" characters are normally illegal, so you would have to use the square brackets quotes.

As for the schema name, I would recommend not to write it, as if someday the schema name of the table you want to access is not dbo, your code might break.